How can voting by mail provide voting secrecy in the US elections?
As a foreigner watching the unfolding US elections, it really strikes me as odd that voting by mail is a valid way to vote when, IMHO, it cannot be guaranteed to be secret.
I'm assuming secrecy is paramount in every state election. In fact, checking the article II, section 7 of the constitution of New York says (emphasis by me):

All elections by the citizens [...] shall be by [some method]
prescribed by law, provided that secrecy in voting be preserved.

But how can the secrecy be guaranteed when it's done at someone's home? How can it be guaranteed that the person voting wasn't coerced or forced to vote against his/her will?
Even if the voter wasn't coerced, how can it be guaranteed that someone didn't peek over your shoulder and saw who you voted for? Or perhaps there was a camera which recorded you checking one candidate's box. Heck, someone might even record their vote and post it on social media?
In short, there cannot be the expectation of secrecy when there are no measures to assure it. Is there a formal reasoning why voting by mail is supposed to guarantee secrecy?

I guess this is partly inspired by https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/89656/how-does-new-york-preserve-the-privacy-of-voters-in-a-public-space which quotes the same constition.

I've not read the details in https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2024/nov/01/republicans-supreme-court-pennsylvania-ballots but SCOTUS seems to have ruled that even omitting the "secrecy sleeve" does not make a vote invalid. In fact, there are no details for now as SCOTUS gave an emergency decision, with no justification provided.

I have no idea about NY specifically, but in principle mail-in ballots can allow secret voting if it is possible to override a mail-in vote with a later mail-in vote which replaces it, or an in-person vote which replaces it. This would mean that even if somebody watched you complete a mail-in ballot, saw who you voted for, and watched you walk to the post box to send it off, they still would not actually know that your vote would be for that candidate.

@kaya3: revoting is useful in case of coerced votes, but useless in case of voluntarily sold votes.

@264champagnebottlesonice: It's still useful, because it makes the proof useless.  If the vote buyer is willing to accept "cross my fingers I won't revote" they probably would have accepted the "cross my fingers I tell you the truth about my secret vote" too

@264champagnebottlesonice: Note that secrecy sleeves are only used in some states in the first place. California does not provide them (at least in my county, anyway). You just put the ballot in the envelope, and the envelope in the mail.

@BenVoigt: you can monitor whether someone is going to a polling station. Yeah, somewhat expensive, so granted it raises the cost. But if you can buy or be an election observer...

People can complete their ballot in private. Most people have access to private places where someone can't peak over your shoulder some of the time. This is hardly remarkable. And, given the stakes it isn't essential that the level of secrecy of a ballot have the same resistance to even the most extraordinary methods to spy on the voter that one would require for national security secrets. There is no percentage in expending those kinds of resources on determining how an ordinary voter casts their ballot.
Once the ballot is completed, it is typically put in a sleeve or envelope that conceals what was marked upon it. The envelope is typically signed to affirm that this was done in a proper manner.
Once it is placed in a ballot box or mailbox, the sealed envelope is delivered to a vote counter (unless the ballot box is also a vote counting machine). The identifying information on the envelope and/or sleeve is discarded in the process of opening the sealed envelope. Then, the anonymized ballot is counted.
The important thing, from the perspective of the New York State Constitution, is that the voting method makes secrecy possible for the voter, not that it is 100% certain that it is maintained in every single instance if a voter permits it. Secrecy is generally a protection for the voter and not for the state (although some states have criminalized taking a photo of your ballot).

You're assuming someone secretly spies on you while you fill in your ballot, but what about in a controlling relationship?  What if they insist on watching you do your ballot, and will punish you if you do it without them there?

@Ryan_L as a practical matter other forms of voting pose similar problems and there is a huge continuum between quid pro quo duress and less insidious and even helpful forms of guidance about an election.

optional secrecy isn't a protection for the voter, because they can be punished for availing themselves of it.  See https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/57835/2120

@BenVoigt Varies from state to state.

@ohwilleke: Whether the secrecy is optional varies from state to state, but the logical argument remains valid.

@BenVoigt Nice answer you had on the question you shared here in the comments. "Only when secrecy is universal does it actually protect against coercion" --> That's the point! Mail voting cannot guarantee that, so I assume vote secrecy is a right, not a duty. Where I live elections are 100% in person and you must leave your electronic devices in a table far away from the ballot box to (try to) ensure secrecy...

@gmauch In person voting can't guarantee that someone won't be subject to undue influence in all cases either.

What about being forced to fill the ballot and the envelope in your house in front of the eyes of a criminal who coerces you into voting for someone (either by giving your some money or by pointing you a gun or something else) and also goes with you to the collecting box in order to assure that your vote was fullfilled? And also does that in the last minutes so you can't "revote"?

@VictorStafusa There is no voting system on Earth that it isn't possible to commit crimes to tamper with and there never will be. The best we can do is to require someone to commit a crime to tamper with it. Also, don't forget, a secret ballot isn't even a federal constitutional right (even though it may be one under state law). Voting was done publicly for all to see for many decades in early U.S. history. The modern consensus is that it is preferable to have secret ballots, but one can have a legitimate democracy without them. The duress in this example is a step beyond mere secrecy issues.

@VictorStafusa From the perspective of the benefit of secret ballots to the democratic system, perfect 100% compliance isn't critical. Even if the secrecy of 1% of the ballots (on the order of 1.5 million of them nationally), was compromised, it wouldn't remove the benefit to a democracy of a system of secret ballots.

Well, Brazil is very different: The secrecy is sacred. You aren't allowed to fill or deposit your ballot in the presence of other people. The voting is 100% electronic, but even when that fails and reverts to paper voting, you must deposit your vote as soon as you fill it and immediately leave. Filming or photographing your voting or your ballot is a crime and can make you go to jail. If your secrecy can't be guaranteed, you aren't allowed to vote. Also public voting was a thing until 1930, and it was very bad: gangs could even kill people who didn't vote the way they wanted to.
